# Python ctype struct with array of structs

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes

I have some struct, with dynamic entries count. I receiving bytearray from UDP and  parsing this message as follows:

```
class MsgStruct(Structure):
    _pack_ = 1

    def __init__(self, data=None):
        if data:
            self.unpack(data)

    def unpack(self, raw):
        fit = sizeof(self)
        memmove(addressof(self), raw[:fit], fit)

    def pack(self):
        return bytearray(self)[:]

    def size(self):
        return sizeof(self)


class MessageEntry(MsgStruct):

    _fields_ = [
        ('type', c_byte),
        ('flag', c_byte),
        ('count', c_int)]


class Message(MsgStruct):

    _fields_ = [
        ('id', c_int),
        ('entry_count', c_int)]

    entries = []

    def __init__(self, data=None):
        MsgStruct.__init__(self, data=data)
        if data:
            self.parseEntries(data[self.entry_count:])

    def parseEntries(self, data):
        offset = 0
        size = sizeof(MessageEntry())
        for count in range(self.entry_count):
            entry = MessageEntry(data[offset:offset+size])
            self.entries.append(entry)
            offset += size
```

but I think there is a better way to parsing the message using ctypes.Array or POINTER and trying this:

```
class Message(MsgStruct):

    _fields_ = [
        ('id', c_int),
        ('entry_count', c_int),
        ('entries', POINTER(MessageEntry))]

    def __init__(self, data=None):
        MsgStruct.__init__(self, data=data)
        if data:
            self.parseEntries(data[self.entry_count:])

    def parseEntries(self, data):
        offset = 0
        size = sizeof(MessageEntry())
        elems = (MessageEntry * self.entry_count)()
        self.entries = cast(elems, POINTER(MessageEntry))
        for count in range(self.entry_count):
            self.entries[count] = MessageEntry(data[offset:offset+size])
            offset += size
```

But when I try to print entries, i'm fall into an endless cycle

```
msg = Message(x)
for i in msg.entries:
    print(i)
```

What wrong i doing?
Is there another way to parsing message with dynamic entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to start with the note that I don't see where is the *entry_count* attribute initialized.

Iterating over a pointer as if it was a **sized** array is conceptually wrong (as also pointed out in [[Python 3]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes)). In *C*, it's possible to go beyond an array bounds, but *ctypes* forbids it. 
Here's a simpler example that uses `ctypes.c_char` as the base type (*MessageEntry* correspondent).

*code.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import ctypes


def main():
    CharArr5 = ctypes.c_char * 5
    b5 = b"12345"
    ca5 = CharArr5(*b5)
    print("Print array ...")
    for c in ca5:
        print(c)

    cp = ctypes.cast(ca5, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char))
    max_values = 10
    print("\nPrint pointer (max {:d} values) ...".format(max_values))
    for idx, c in enumerate(cp):
        print(c)
        if idx >= max_values:
            print("Max value number reached.")
            break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
```

**Output**:

> ```py
> (py_064_03.06.08_test0) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q054178876>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.06.08_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code.py
> Python 3.6.8 (tags/v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 00:16:47) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> Print array ...
> b'1'
> b'2'
> b'3'
> b'4'
> b'5'
>
> Print pointer (max 10 values) ...
> b'1'
> b'2'
> b'3'
> b'4'
> b'5'
> b'\x00'
> b'\x00'
> b'\x00'
> b'\x00'
> b'\x00'
> b'\x00'
> Max value number reached.
> ```

As seen, it **is** possible to iterate over the pointer, but the loop never ends (it will end when reaching an unavailable / invalid memory address, and the program will *segfault* (*Access Violation*)).

Assuming that *entry_count* is properly initialized (**if not, make sure to initialize it**), use it to keep the loop inside bounds (as shown below):

```py
for idx in range(msg.entry_count):
    msg.entries[idx]  # Do smth with it
    # ...
```

```py
for idx, entry in enumerate(msg.entries):
    if idx >= msg.entry_count:
        break
    entry  # Do smth with it
    # ...
```

Or you could use one of the above to implement *Iterator Protocol* for *Message*.